# Is it possible to prevent dragging the shell in SWT for Mac OS when using Shell.getToolBar()?

Tags: java, macos, swt, toolbar

It is possible to place any type of custom control into the shell's trim area in SWT using Shell.getToolBar() introduced in SWT 3.7. One needs to create a ToolItem with SWT.SEPARATOR style and assign it a custom control. My "custom control" is the entire tool bar area including some Composite based custom widgets.

See this bug comment for what I have done roughly:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=222859#c124

The problem is that the user may drag the shell by clicking into an "empty" area of the unified tool bar. And it appears my custom control is regarded as "empty space". One of my controls supports drag&drop. However, when it's placed in the unified tool bar area, dragging drags the shell, not the widget contents that are supposed to be draggable. Actually, both happens at the same time. So all I would need is to somehow stop the event from being processed any further. Attaching a Listener for SWT.MouseDown to my custom control and setting event.doit to false doesn't work.